# ./studio.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\224J%\022\211D\242Q'

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

This problem comes when I am trying to open Android studio on Ubuntu
if anyone want to solve then solve it.

[image: Problem]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly attach your picture - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try to do this way

`cd android-studio/bin
sh studio.sh`

Comment: i do this but problem is same